# Is $\max \left (\frac{2}{\Vert w \Vert} \right )$ the same as $\min(\Vert w \Vert)$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

I was reading [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/support-vector-machines-dual-formulation-quadratic-programming-sequential-minimal-optimization-57f4387ce4dd) on [support vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) (SVMs), which claims

$$\max \left (\frac{2}{\Vert w \Vert } \right) = \min(\Vert w \Vert)$$

How can that possible be? What happened to $2$? Even one teacher [claimed](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Edyer/cs540/notes/10_svm.pdf) the same

[image]

Comment: This could be an error, or it could highly depend on the context of the problem (what $w$ is, for example).

Comment: Reading the article, I'm wondering if that should be an argmax and an argmin (which could make sense).  Anyway, I just noticed the article has emojis in it, so I wouldn't take it too seriously.

Comment: @Randall Well, that equation exist elsewere too.

Comment: I agree with @Randall, it's mostly likely asking for the $w$ which maximises $2/|w|$, which is the same as the value of $w$ which minimise $|w|$ and also $|w|^2$.

Comment: It doesn't say they are equal, just that they are equivalent problems. They will have the same optimal solutions, but obviously with different objective values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0 < a < b$. Note that

$$\underset{x \in [a,b]}{\operatorname{argmax}} \frac2x = a = \underset{x \in [a,b]}{\operatorname{argmin}} x$$ even though

$$\frac2a = \underset{x \in [a,b]}{\max} \frac2x \color{blue}{\neq} \underset{x \in [a,b]}{\min} x = a$$

Comment: Please, do even an example =)

Comment: Did not really understand completly. Is there a difference between argmax and max?

Comment: @euraad Yes, $\operatorname{argmax}$ is a **maximizer** $x^*$ whereas $\max$ is the **maximum** $f (x^*)$.  The former is an **input** of $f$ whereas the latter is an **output**. Note that $\operatorname{argmax}$ stands for "argument that maximizes" or "input that maximizes".

Comment: Hmm...I think you could clarifying this with an example. Good work anyway! :)

Comment: @euraad I already provided an example in my answer, where $f (x) = \frac2x$ and $g (x) = x$ are the objectives, where the optimal input is $x = a$ and the optimal output is $f(a)=\frac2a$ or $g(a) = a$